# Is it possible to store PHP class definitions on application server to be reused whenever required by creating an object?

Tags: php, class, orm, persistence

I am developing a small application in PHP and trying MVC architecture. My View part has HTML/CSS/Javascript and Controller will be php submit scripts.

Can I write recurringly used class definitions and store them on application server through some framework so that in the submit scripts i need to only create an object and cal methods.

Just to clarify, i am not taking about require_once, i don't want that class definition code to be included in each time. I want that code to stored on server in some framework and it should be called only when i create a new object in my php pages. This will be my Model part to encapsulate business process logic. It will contain ORM and other classes as well.

I have searched for PHP ORM frameworks but i need some framework for storing classes other than those which communicate with database and provide simple business process logic.

Can anyone please provide whether it is possible and if yes then which frameworks are available for that??

Comment: Have you looked at autoloading your classes http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: please , do not confuse MVC's model layer with ORMs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into autoloaders?
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

```
<?php
function __autoload($class){
    require_once "classes/$class.php";
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
```